# Creating new object in Core Data: create first or upon return?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

So I'm struggling with Core Data. I'm finding there are many ways to do the same thing, and that if you try to build the app using Storyboards and UIManagedDocuments you need to read all the tutorials and examples older than last year with a translation sheet. Today's question is about finding the best practice when adding a new managed object.  I've seen examples done both ways:

1. Create the new managed object in a table view controller (after clicking +) and giving that new shining managed object to the subordinate "Add" view controller to get user input for all the object attributes.  This seems simple, and the returned object is simple to understand because it contains all the individual attributes.  But I've seen example code in this "Add" view controller for a "cancel" button that deletes the managed object passed in and then calls Save Context before dismissing itself.  Functional, but the MVC training gnome on my shoulder is screaming at me about having this subordinate Add View delete an object and *horrors* directly call Save Context.  The Recipe example code from Apple appears to use this method.
2. Send nothing to the Add view controller, and have it send back a delegate call the table view controller that returns each of the attributes as a separate passed parameter.  So the return method becomes really long:  controller:(UIViewController *)controller didReturnFirstName:(NSString *)firstName andLastName:(NSString *)lastName andStreetAddress:(NSString *) and... and... and..   But this is SO consistent with MVC dogma because the managed object is created back in the table view controller when it receives all the individual attributes, and the "Add" view never touches the Model(Core Data), or throws away an unused managed object when the user changes their mind.
   Even with chained delegated methods, I'm still debating with myself which is a better method.  Comments and ideas from those who've lived with both forms would be a welcome addition.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is acceptable for the data model to send 1 managed object to the view controller to display.  For example, your contacts.  When you view one contact, I would not expect the saved data model to be passing each field individually to the view controller, but instead passed 1 managed object that contacts all the information for that one contact.  For deleting an object, maybe treat it as a target-action to the view controller and then have the view controller message the data class to delete that object...

Comment: Thanks, Nick.  I agree sending one object to a view controller to display is a consistent and solid tactic.  I'm asking about the creation process, where you need to (maybe) add one new item to your database.  Do you create the new managed object in the prepare for segue method and pass it to the new controller, or do you wait and create a new object once the subordinate view returns?

Comment: +1 for well worded question which is EXACTLY what I wanted to ask, and is moreover something basic enough that it should be laid out in apple documentation or any number of tutorials

Answer (score 1):

It you look at the example in Apple's [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CreatingAddView/CreatingAddView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH6-SW1), they accomplish this task by doing a number of things outlined below, in this case they have a modal view appear to input the information that is to be added to the data model:

1. In the modal view that appears, they create a protocol to handle either dismissing the view or saving the data and a property of type id that implements that protocol to be the delagate, this insures whatever object that is implments the required methods
2. In the view controller that created the modal view, they implement the protocol, including saving the object to the data model and dismissing the modal view
3. In the view controller that created the modal, they set the view controller that created the modal view as the modal view delegate during the seque to the modal

So, to summarize,  in the modal view to collect the new data you need to:
create a protocol and property in .h and synthesize it

```
 @protocol yourProtocol <NSObject>;
 //methods that determine what happens based on what user does, it would save your core data object
 @end

 @property(nonatomic, weak) id<yourProtocol> delegate;
```

Then, in the modal view .m file you call those methods on the delegate, likely when they pick save or done, so a method for each probably as IBAction connected to a button

```
 [self.delegate myMethod];
```

In the view that presented the modal view, you implement the protocol in the .h file

```
 @interface viewController() <yourProtocol>
```

and finally, add your methods to the view controller that presented the modal view's .m file, this should include removing the view and saving your core data.  According to Apple and other sources, the view controller that caused the popup/modal, etc... should be the one that dismisses it.  Then, in the seque using the seque indentfying, set the view controller that is presented int he modal view as the modal view's delegate.

Comment: Nick - I don't know why you and I keep talking past each other.  I agree with all you said.  The tutorial code only gathers 2 pieces of user data (bird name and location), so passing those two pieces of information from the modal view back to the delegate is somewhat simple.  But I'm anticipating expanding the number of fields of data input and think it becomes cumbersome when the delegate method has 10 or more separate passed parameters.

Comment: Yes, and what I'm saying is to just pass the "bird object" that contains all 10 parameters.

Comment: Ahhhh...   Thanks.  I'm rewriting the code now to do that.   Thanks again for your comments.  I appreciate them.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there are many approaches to take on this one.

It sounds as if you are starting with a context that may not be saved, so in order to be able to get back to your starting point I would tackle it like this:

1. Start by creating a new NSManagedObject to be used as a temporary object which gets passed to your "Edit" view.
2. If you are editing an existing object, copy the attributes from the existing object into this new temporary object (You can use a quick for loop to copy them all generically).  Otherwise proceed with the newly created object.
3. Pass the temporary object to the "Edit" view controller and have it treat both cases the same.
   a. If the user presses cancel, have either a protocol or delegate method which notifies the tableview and the tableview then simply discards the temporary object.
   b. If they press save, notify the tableview and then copy the attributes from the temporary copy back to the original and delete the temporary object (if it is an edit operation), or just leave it as the newly created object if it was an "Add" operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right approach would actually be to create a new, separate `NSManagedObjectContext` for your AddController (if a new item is to be created) or EditController (if an existing item is to be modified).

Chose A) or B) depending on your SDK:

A) You then have the choice to either save changes in that context, or discard the context.

In case of a "save", you can **merge** the changes into the TableController's `ManagedObjectContext` through Notifications (`NSManagedObjectDidSaveNotification`).

In case of a 'cancel", you can just discard the separate context.

B) Alternatively, if you're on OSX 10.7(+), you could use nested `NSManagedObjectContext`s, creating an `NSManagedObjectContext` in AddController (the child context), and settings it's parentContext to the TableController's `NSManagedObjectContext`.

In case of a "save", you'd save the child context, and the parent context.

In case of a "cancel", you'd just discard the child context.

See a detailed example of this in Apple's CoreDataBooks example http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer so feel free to ignore, but neither is any of the others (so far) a complete answer, and I feel the need to add some points without creating a new question, because I really want to get to the bottom of this too. In particular the answer should deal with

- what happens when you Cancel vs Save
- what if you want to use the same controller for editing an existing entity rather than creating a new one

Nicks answer deals with apple's (current) convention for passing data back, but is not a complete answer because that tutorial does not deal with core-data managed objects, and apples own samples that do use managed objects do it differently.

But on this subject, I find that the delegate convention is unwieldy in some cases and was happy to read this from a more experienced developer:
http://robsprogramknowledge.blogspot.pt/2012/05/back-segues.html

Rob details different mechanisms for that which are *all equally valid*, including the protocol/delegate convention (Nick's), using a data object without a protocol (so-called "shared memory") - more like some of the others suggested, and - my favourite - using a block. 
A block is a nice option because, while it works like a delegate, the code remains entirely in context in the "parent" viewcontrollers source

However, the "shared memory" makes more sense because, as you say, using anything other than the data (managed) object which you've *already designed* to pass all of these properties around just seems silly.

The issue for me then is, what's the convention for creating these managed objects, passing them around, then either
1. saving changes
2. canceling changes
3. canceling creation of a new entity altogether

Inafzigers answer above works something like this, but why all that copying of properties? Can't I just *not save* my changes?

Apple' CoreDataBooks seems to deal with this by creating a *child* ManagedObjectContext and a new entity in that context (insertNewObjectForEntityForName) in the prepareForSegue, and in the delegate method (when it comes back):
- if Save was clicked, it saves both this new ManagedObjectContext and the parent FetchedResultsContext to store the object 
- if Cancel was clicked it does nothing, effectively discarding the new managed object context, and thus, presumably, the new object

So this *might* be the conventional approach, except that:

- There is a comment in the code of that sample (CoreDataBooks RootViewController.m) which states that the two managed contexts are not necessary, implying that you might be able to do the same with just one. Here's the full comment:
     IMPORTANT: It's not necessary to use a second context for this. You could just use the existing context, which would simplify some of the code -- you wouldn't need to perform two saves, for example. This implementation, though, illustrates a pattern that may sometimes be useful (where you want to maintain a separate set of edits).
- CoreDataBooks does not use a UIManagedDocument - not sure if that makes a difference

What's not clear to me is, do we really to use insertNewObjectForEntityForName to create the managed object? What about just creating the object and then only inserting it later if the user hit Save?

Also what about if we do an Edit and a Cancel - can we use the undo manager to get rid of changes?

Comment: I suggested using the temporary object for the situation where you have other changes made in the context that you need to preserve and can't just assume that everything is already saved when you start.  If you are starting at a point where you know that there are no previous edits (or you can safely discard them if they exist) then you don't need the temporary object at all.  I thought that I addressed that in the second sentence of my answer.  :)